# ListView nested scrolling on API<21

Tags: android, android-listview, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout

Title is clear. I'm having this layout:

```
_________________
|_______________| <- Toolbar    
|___|___|___|___| <- Tablayout
|               |
|               |
|   ViewPager   |
|               |
|_______________|
```

Both toolbar and tablayout are inside an `AppBarLayout`, so I can use scroll flags to hide the toolbar on scrolling toward the top. The problem is that this only works with nested-scrolling-supported views. Most of the tabs - I mean, most of the pages - are `support.v4.NestedScrollView`s, so that is OK; others are (and need to be) `ListView`s.

From Lollipop on, I can simply add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` to the list view, and the toolbar hides correctly on scroll.

On API<21, though, there's no such attribute and the toolbar doesn't hide. Even more important, the very last items in the list are hidden, because of some measuring bug in `CoordinatorLayout`: listview acts as if it had the space currently occupied by the toolbar.

Solutions:

- Switch to `RecyclerView`, which does support nested scrolling: I can't, because I need to use an external-library adapter that works only with adapter views and that I can't replace (namely, `ParseQueryAdapter`);
- Extend `ListView` and implement nested scrolling: seems way to complicated;
- Extend `ListView` and implement some workaround, like measuring stuff to avoid the last-item issue or (and) a custom behavior to make the toolbar hide: seems complicated too;
- Use some layout trick: found none.

Any help?

For example, I (desperately) tried:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

But this way the `ListView` is not laid out as `match_parent`. I get a little view with small height, and the rest of the page is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get nested scrolling working on `ListView` - otherwise it wouldn't require the modifications that were done in API 21.

You'll note that the current [Parse SDK](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/) has actually removed `ParseQueryAdapter` entirely. Given that, it may make sense to start building your own `RecyclerView` based adapter using the [Parse query APIs directly](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries).

Comment: I'm not on the very last release, but I remember that class not being listed in the public APIs for long. Thank you, however, for the "you can't" - I spent some hours dealing with NestedScrolling interfaces.

Comment: "there is no way to get nested scrolling working on ListView". There is ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(ListView, boolean);

Comment: @Dogcat - which does nothing prior to API 21. It just saves you from having to check the API level.

Comment: @Dogcat - the [pre-API 21 source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/compat/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.java#965) requires the view to implement the Support Library's `NestedScrollingChild` interface, which a framework class like `ListView` will never do. It is only on [API 21+](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/compat/api21/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompatLollipop.java#148) that it calls through to the framework `setNestedScrollingEnabled`, which `ListView` does implement.

Answer (score 1):

For those intersted in the specific `ParseQueryAdapter` issue,

- Guys at parse.com are working on a [RecyclerView.Adapter version](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/issues/58);
- There's a [beta version of it](https://github.com/lukas1994/ParseUI-Android/blob/82a2510395624439a29becff9316f63c2a8240b8/ParseLoginUI/src/main/java/com/parse/ParseQueryRecyclerViewAdapter.java).