# ListView not expanding inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, nestedscrollview

I am using `CoordinatorLayout` in my activity page. In that there is `ListView` below the app bar. But its not working when I use `ListView` instead of `NestedScrollView`. And if I put `ListView` inside `NestedScrollView`, `ListView` is not expanding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6211286

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For the `CoordinatorLayout` to work properly you need the scrolling child to implement [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html). Such classes are `NestedScrollView` and `RecyclerView`.

To say it short - just use a `RecyclerView` for your scrolling content and it'll work correctly :)

P.S. As a side note, I don't see a reason why you'd use a `ListView` anymore. I know it's a habit and it's easier to setup (because you've done it many times), but using a `RecyclerView` is the recommended way anyways.

Comment: I dont see a fastscroll and section adapter implementation for recycler view yet

Comment: How can I implement Expandable listview

Comment: RecyclerView doesn't handle the CursorAdapter. This could be a good reason!

Comment: You could use Shywims custom CursorRecyclerView Adapter:   https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b

Comment: more details on should or should we not replace ListView with Recycler view
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392554/should-we-use-recyclerview-to-replace-listview

Comment: Calling ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listView, true) does the trick with a ListView.

Comment: @Dogcat no, it's not. Docs "If this view does not implement nested scrolling this will have no effect."

Comment: "I don't see a reason why you'd use a ListView anymore" Can't you just answer the ... question?

Answer (score 73):

you can fix it when you add `addtribute` `android:fillViewport="true"` in `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` :) . This my code.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_myContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        >
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me too. The ListView content isn't scrollable.

Comment: May I know your API level?

Comment: Listview not scrolling

Comment: android:fillViewport="true" works like a charm. Also keep in mind that a recycler view may be more appropriate in most cases (e.g. the whole list or individual items updates dynamically at runtime).

Comment: Worked with me 
So Thanks , you are really saved my time. just Added the tag   android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: Worked for me +1. I have a ConstraintLayout within the NestedScrollView and it didn't scale up to full height without that flag.

Comment: Try enabling programmatically  like "nestedScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);"

Comment: It helped. I have spent two days searching for the solution.

Comment: Well it did expand the viewport, but it isn't scrollable for me.

Answer (score 51):

on Lollipop onwards you can use

```
setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

on your ListView/GridView/ScrollableView. From the documentation

> Enable or disable nested scrolling for this view

if you need backwards compatibility with older version of the OS you'll have to use the `RecyclerView`. You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean))

Edit. 
 `ViewCompat` has the static method `setNestedScrollingEnabled(View, boolean)`. Eg.

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listView, true)
```

thanks to `@Dogcat` for pointing it out

Comment: This answer should definitely be upvoted and even set as the correct answer now.
I ended up changing my implementation to a `RecyclerView` because I only read the answer that was accepted as the answer. Yes of course I could've read all the answers, but the first one worked for me - if was just a hassle to change the implementation ;-)

Comment: You just saved me! And yes this should be the accepted answer

Comment: No, it's not working. Docs say "If this view does not implement nested scrolling this will have no effect."

Comment: The ViewCompat does nothing before Android Lolipop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811121/listview-nested-scrolling-on-api21

Answer (score 15):

this is what worked for me.

set `android:fillViewport="true"` on the `NestedScrollView`

add One Layout Element as Child to `NestedScrollView`. In my case `LinearLayout` and then 
set `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` on `ListView` 
Make `ListView` a child of `LinearLayout`

Good to go

Comment: I was about to say the same thing until I read this. This solution is good for API 21+

Comment: Only solution that's worked for me. And Using the LinearLayout helps in composing a composite ui nested inside the outer NestedScrollView. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Just put `android:fillViewport="true"` inside you `NestedScrollView` Tag

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: @Aziz actually I was also facing same problem and it worked. on setting "fillViewport" true it stretch the content's height to the viewport's boundaries,

Answer (score 9):

You listview will scroll. Hope help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:fillViewport="true"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

         <ListView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
         </ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Below code worked for me:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listView, true);
```

Your `ListView` should be inside `NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your ListView with `RecyclerView` if possible else create your customListView and set `onMeasure` of `ListView` to this:

```
 public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
```

This `ListView` won't be able to scroll anymore and can be used inside `NestedScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't scroll listview inside a nestedscrollview.Use Recyclerview with nestedscrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="76dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            app:border_color="#FF000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="IRFAN QURESHI"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="irfan123@gmail.com" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/login_email_bg_round_rect_shape"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="POST A QUERY" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <!--<ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SIGN OUT" />
        <ImageView
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" tag inside your NestedScrollView.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scrollbars="none"
  android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
   <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list_myContent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scrollbars="vertical">
  </ListView>
```

Comment: This one is only supported in API 21 and higher. Unfortunately I'm building for 16 minimum.