# Do I have to implement RecyclerView in order to scroll out a view out of screen

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have following layout:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to scroll out the ViewPager out of the screen when you scroll in any of the listviews at the half bottom of the screen. As the ViewPager would be getting out of the screen the ListViews should take up more and more screen. Toolbar should stay pinned.

I was having look at the [Support Design Library.](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

In my case from the examples the most interesting piece of code was this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <! -- Your Scrollable View -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Do **I need to change my ListViews to RecyclerViews** in order to achieve scrolling out the ViewPager from the screen - while the ListViews would increase their height as the ViewPager would getting out of the screen? Is that even **possible** with the **Coordinator** Layout?

Comment: github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager  you can use this library.

Comment: ListView supports nested scrolling only on API > 21 (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811121/listview-nested-scrolling-on-api21 ). So you either target these devices or use RecyclerView.