# How to setNestedScrollingEnabled in pre-lollipop devices.

Tags: android, listview, scroll, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've a layout in which Root view is **CoordinatorLayout** and there is a **TabLayout** and a **ViewPager**. And there are multiple fragments are initialized in viewpager using **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**.
Some fragments are using **ListView** and some are using **RecyclerView**. But view with **ListView** are not scrolling properly while the view with **RecyclerView** are working fine.
And if I'm using:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listView, true);
```

It only works with api level 21 or higher. Can anyone help me here.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: ListView dose not support nested scroll with pre-lollipop(api < 21). Here is similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811121/listview-nested-scrolling-on-api21

Comment: Yes @nshmura, thats the my question. How can we achieve it or I've to use RecyclerView.

Comment: I think the best way is to use `RecyclerView`. Maybe `ListView` with `NestedScrollView` works, but I did not try.