# How to show ListView and ExpandedListView inside scrollview on one activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, scrollview, expandablelistview

I have activity in which i am showing some textfield and below these texfield there are two list one `ListView` and another is `ExpandableListView`. But problem is that `Listview` and `ExpandableListView` are not showing all item and not scrolling!

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        tools:context="dotphi.android.com.zuffl.JobDetailsFragment">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/FirstLinearLayout">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.60"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text=""/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/radio_online"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_tick_inside_circle"
                        android:clickable="false"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/radio_live"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_wifi_gray"
                        android:clickable="false"/>


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/radio_images"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_attachments_grey"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/SecondLinearLayout"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <dotphi.android.com.zuffl.RoundedImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_profile"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.55"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/lr_profile">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView14"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Posted By"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#000"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_time"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#eee" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ThirdLinearLayout">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_location"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.24"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_location_blue" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.56"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Location"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#000"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_location"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_map"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:layout_weight="0.18"
                        android:text="View Map"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#eee" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ForthLinearLayout">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_calendar"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Due Date"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_date"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text=""/>

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#eee" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/FifthLinearLayout">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_rupee"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"
                        android:src="@drawable/task_price" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Task Price"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_price"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_status"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_button_style"
                        android:text="Earn"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:background="#eee" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/ButtonLinearLayout">


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_complete"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_button_style"
                        android:text="Complete"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_button_style"
                        android:text="Cancel"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:background="#eee" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/SixthLinearLayout">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView7"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Description"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#000" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_description"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:text="" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:background="#eee" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/SeventhLinearLayout">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView8"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Offers"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#000"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_tt"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:text="View your offers below, check the Zuffl Worker's profile and then accept an offer to get started." />

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/offers_list"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_more_review"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@drawable/edit_button_style"
                            android:text="See More Offer"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView9"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Questions"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#000" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/commenttext"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
                                android:gravity="top"
                                android:hint="Ask question"
                                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                                android:minLines="3"
                                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                android:textSize="16sp" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/add"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="end"
                            android:background="@drawable/edit_button_style"
                            android:text="Send"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />


                        <ExpandableListView
                            android:id="@+id/commentList"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                            android:background="@drawable/edit_button_style"
                            android:text="See More Comments"
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            />
                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/divider2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0.2dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0"
                            android:background="#eee" />



                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Add your layout file

Comment: ListViews, Scroll views nested inside each other exhibit this character.
Checkout https://github.com/paolorotolo/ExpandableHeightListView. This might solve your problem.

Comment: have you tried setting some hardcoded size to your Expandable List View ?

Comment: No. I have set up the height wrap_content of ListView and ExpandableListView in xml file.

Comment: Perhaps this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32811121/1889768) will help you.

Comment: Also I recommend using the newer RecyclerView. Where you can enable nested scrolling by simply calling `RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)` method.