# What is equivalent to Android.Widget.ListView.NestedScrollingEnabled in versions before 21?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.listview

I am developing custom renderer for android to enable the nested scrolling for a `ListView` and I'm using `Android.Widget.ListView.NestedScrollingEnabled` attribute and it works fine but that attribute is added in API level 21 and I am wondering what is equivalent to it in versions before 21?

Answer (score 0):

If you check [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32814153/7462031) answer on ListView nested scrolling on API<21

It clearly says:

> Unfortunately, there is no way to get nested scrolling working on ListView - otherwise it wouldn't require the modifications that were done in API 21.

Also, there is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50874885/7462031) claiming to have a solution so you can check it.

Revert in case of queries